# Is there a way to let excel recognize decimal placement?

Tags: excel, export-to-csv, decimal-point

I've written a csv file with the `.to_csv` function. This worked fine but when I open the csv file in excel, excel doesn't recognise the decimal placement.

For example:
A number that was supposed to be `100611.52421..` is displayed in Excel as `1006115242123330`. I know nothing went wrong with writing the file because when I display the csv file in visual studio code I can see the dot.
Does anyone know how I can properly open the csv file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Import the text file instead of opening directly. In the import wizard there is an option to specify the character to be considered decimal separator in Advanced options

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your CSV file. I believe your regional settings are wrong: the dot is not recognised as a decimal separator.
In order to fix this, check the following in your configuration settings:

[image]